# Code Management ,different code for different environment under same package

Tags: java, maven-2, build-management

I have an application which has the client code to a web service ,  the application was tested successfully and moved to production , Live deployment was such that the client had to be generated again and practically we have the same code with two different clients under the same package.

Client 
       Package a.a   A.java  QA Client file 
       Package a.a   A.java  Live Client file

The problem is the build management for such scenario , any suggestion how this can be effectively managed .

Comment: What kind of client code do you have? What has to be generated again? Sounds like having different configurations for productive and test environment. In this case the configuration files should change not the code.

Comment: The client consists of apache cxf client java files , these java files have strong refrences to the environment such as queue name and context and etc etc.

Comment: Do you mean that you've hard-coded configuration details into your Java?